# Settings for Custom Tab in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

If you go into amend Settings for a custom tab that you have created before, is there anyway to get the existing websiteUrl and contentUrl values in your configuration page?

The microsoftTeams.getContext method doesn't seem to make these Urls available (like it does entityId).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to persist this your side (e.g. in a database), and re-query them from your settings page. This is exactly why the "save" button won't become enabled until you're ready for it (by calling `microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState`) - it's for your code to do whatever it needs before allowing the user to actually save any changes.

Comment: Pity. For a standard tab (e.g. Website, Word) when yo go into amend the settings, Teams automatically pre-populates existing parameters like websiteUrl. So it has these values in it's  own settings store. All these simply need to be made available via getcontext. It makes entityId available so why not the others. Anyway, that's life I suppose.